# Python 3.x: Java valueOf() equivalent in Python 3.x

Tags: java, python-3.x, value-of

Whilest learning Python 3 and converting some of my code from Java to Python 3.3 I came across a small problem I haven't been able to fix.
In Java I have this code (just dummy code to make it smaller):

```
public enum Mapping {
    C11{public int getMapping(){ return 1;}},
    C12{public int getMapping(){ return 2;}},
    public abstract int getMapping();
}

String s = "C11";
System.out.println(Mapping.valueOf(s))
```

Works fine and prints the requisted '1'
Trying to do this in Python doesn't work that easy (yet). I tried to imitate an Enum with:

```
class Mapping:
    C11=1
    C12=2

s = 'C11'
print(Mapping.Mapping.(magic should happen here).s)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to convert a string to an attribute to be called like that (or something similar).
I need this because I have a HUGE list in the class Mapping and need to convert seemingly random words read from a text file to an integer mapping.

Comment: Please read [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), not so much because of this specific question, but because it and they way you ask it indicate you're still mostly thinking in Java terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> getattr(Mapping, s)
1
```

From the documentation:

> **getattr(object, name[, default])**
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. *name* must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, *default* is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class Mapping:
    C11=1
    C12=2

print(getattr(Mapping, 'C11')) # prints 1
```